# django get_model returns null when called from __.init__.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
from django.db.models import get_model
modelname=get_model('base','reports')
```

The above code works fine in views.py and django shell,but returns null when called from **init**.py

folder structure is shown below

projectsfolder

--base

----models.py

----views.py

---- **init**.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why my code above doesn't work only @ **__init__**.py.But the code below worked for me.

```
modelname=get_model('base', k['tablename'], seed_cache=False, only_installed=False).
```

Also django fixtures is a better way to  initialise db. :):)

Answer (score 0):

That can't possibly work. Anything in `__init__.py` is always going to be executed the first time anything in that directory is imported. But Django has to import the models in order to register them, so you've got into a chicken-and-egg situation: it won't register them until it imports them, but you're trying to get the models when they're imported...

Can you explain though why you don't simply do `from models import Reports`?

Comment: I can simply import Reports or any other model directly.But what i really want is to dynamically get a model depending on the value stored in a variable.I badly need get_model() to work.:(

Comment: But why do you need it to be done in `__init__.py`? Please give your actual use case.

Comment: i am trying to initialise db with data stored as dict object..on server start.It worked when i manually called my db models.now i have to dynamically call tables and update them.To get these models i need to use get_model()

Comment: Then you *certainly* don't want that to be done in `__init__.py`. Otherwise the initialisation would be done every time a new process is started, which sounds like a very very bad idea.

Comment: No,db initialisation will occur only depending on a flag value which is stored in db